# How to open the wpf application from v4 printer driver

Tags: c#, wpf, wdk, printers, v4-printer-driver

I have a wpf .NET application and I have created a V4 printer driver from Microsoft and have got it installed . Now how can I  open this wpf application from the printer e.g. if user opens any document and select this printer from print option then this wpf application should be opened.
I have searched in Microsoft documents but I am not able to get any idea on it.
Can anyone tell on this.

Comment: Are you trying to override the default print window dialog based on the printer selection?

Comment: yes, here in this case the default print dialog also doesn't open.

Comment: I not sure it is possible to override the preview dialog but with start printing you could try to emulate "out of paper" and show some custom dialog